# Copy OpportunityShare object data to Custom Quote_Share object in Realtime

Tags: standard-objects

We would like to copy all the OpportunityShare object data(records) to Custom Quote_Share object in Realtime like whenever a record inserted/updated in OpportunityShare.

Note*: We can't to create a trigger on OpportunityShare object to do the above job.

Anyone have any suggestion or idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Batch class and schedule it for every day which will SOQL on OpportunityShare object as per the created date and create the new record in Custom Quote_Share object.

let me know if this can solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!. We have already recommended this solution for our customer. We will be running schedule apex job every minutes once to update the data in Quote object.

Comment: There is an issue: Whenever the opptyshare record get deleted, there is no way to get the oppty id to delete Quoteshare object record. Any idea or suggestion?